# Как работать с таблицей превышающей объем оперативной памяти?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, big-data

Есть таблица размерами (10 000 00 X 7) в формате txt около 2ГБ, памяти доступно 2ГБ. Вопрос как обрабатывать данные из таблице если не загружать ее полностью в оперативку. Так же предстоит работать с таблицами весом 30Гб+ на 100млн+ строк. Работаю с помощью Python + pandas.

Comment: А можно пример файла? Не на 2 гига конечно, а маленький. Я бы посмотрел.

Comment: https://www.dask.org/

Comment: Способы, чтобы не думать (но изучать новые либы): `Dask`, `Vaex`. Но по-хорошему сначала нужно разобраться, что вы хотите вообще

Answer (score 0):

Читайте построчно. Постройте индекс по какому смещению (seek) искать нужные строчки